# Unable to authenticate user manually

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code on my login page:

```
    if (authentication method returns true)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket;

        if (cbRemember.Checked)
        {
            ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, tbUsername.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), true, null, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        }
        else
        {
            ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, tbUsername.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), true, null, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        }

        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    }
    else
    {
        errorBox.Visible = true;
    }
```

However the user is still not authenticated after this. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was passing `null` into one of the ticket's parameters. You have to pass string.empty.